# Error when installling sharepoint server 2013 on windows server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, windows-server-2012-r2

I have retrieved a message after completing installing SharePoint 2013 that says

```
"One or more required office components failed to complete successfully. For more information, consult the setup log file".
```

How can this problem be solved?????
[image: Error Image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the prerequisites successfully? Is the server connected to the internet?

Comment: yes , install the prerequisites successfully. no,  the server isn't connected to the internet

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing them? Have you checked the log file from the errror message?

Comment: yes and i find this error in log file in the first installation . then i remove sharepoint and install again but now i cant see this error message in log file : "Error: Command: 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SERVER14\Server Setup Controller\OsrvRedist.exe' failed with error code: 1603. Type: 8::CommandFailed."

Answer (score 0):

Hi before instillation of share point 2013 install the latest windows updates and install the prerequisites and install the share point 2013 binaries

Below is the link for best practice
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396